# How to add and delete record using a single button with the help of onclick function in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

**Add Question Button**

[image]

If I click on the **ADD TO EXAM** button, that particular record should add to the table, and the button should convert to **DELETE TO EXAM** button and vice versa. I have tried all alternatives in Laravel, How can I Add or Remove record?

Comment: Can you share what you tried ?

Comment: I had simply added a insert query by creating a new function but that was not executed after that I deleted that..

Comment: Hey Abhay, welcome to SO. You will have to use javascript/jquery to be able to do what you wanted. Also, we would be able to help you if you show your work as in what you have done and do forth. Follow this link https://www.studentstutorial.com/laravel/laravel-ajax-insert might be what you want. Goodl uck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets take 2 routes for example:

```
Route::post('/add/{id}', 'Controller@addFunction');
Route::delete('/remove/{id}', 'Controller@deleteFunction');
```

Then in your blade file, following is your input button (ID will be exactly your row ID):

```html
<input id="217" type="button" value="Add to Exam" style="color: white; background-color: green;" onclick="clickFunction(this);" />
```

This `clickFunction` will handle your calls & actions (button color & text changes) in result. Following is pure JS code without using a library like jQuery:

```javascript
function clickFunction(event) {         
    var [
        method, action,
        text, color
    ] = (event.value === "Add to Exam") ? [
        'POST', `/add/${event.id}`,
        'Delete from Exam', 'red'
    ] : [
        'DELETE', `/remove/${event.id}`,
        'Add to Exam', 'green'
    ];
    
    fetch(action, {
        method,
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            'Authorization': 'Bearer <Token>'
        }
    })
    .then(() => {
        event.value = text;
        event.style.backgroundColor = color;
        return true;
    })
    .catch((e) => alert(e));
}
```

---

***EDIT***

Change your routes (I'm sharing just one route. Do same with other):

```
Route::post('admin/exams/{id}/add/{question_id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ExamsController@addFunction');
```

Controller:

```
public function addFunction(Request $req, $id, $question_id) {

    DB::table('exam_questions')->insert([
        'exam_id' => $id,
        'question_id' => $question_id
    ]);

    return back()->with('success_msg', 'Question Added Successfully')
}
```

and update Javascript (in the beginning of `clickFunction`):

```javascript
function clickFunction(event) {         
    ...
        'POST', `/admin/exams/${exam_id}/add/${event.id}`,
        'Delete from Exam', 'red'
    ] : [
        'DELETE', `/admin/exams/${exam_id}/remove/${event.id}`,
        'Add to Exam', 'green'
    ];

    // this "exam_id" should be somewhere in your page or table row. You can get it from there using some logics
    
    ...
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233186/discussion-on-answer-by-talesid-how-to-add-and-delete-record-using-a-single-butt).

Comment: `POST -> /admin/exams/17/add/127 404 (Not Found)`  This error is coming now

Comment: check your route file...

Comment: admin/exams/addquestion?exam_id=21 this is the url so do I need to add `addquestion` in route file as well as in script too?

Comment: `Route::post('/admin/exams/{id}/add/{question_id}', 'App\Http\Controllers\Admin\ExamsController@addFunction');`

Comment: in your route `admin/exams/addquestion?exam_id=21` where is the question's ID?

Comment: also if this is your route, why are you using `/admin/exams/{id}/add/{question_id}`??? You definitely have to add this route in your route file so that you won't get 404 not found

Answer (score 0):

Simply create an ajax request through jQuery with the unique row id.

```
$.ajax({
            url: `/module/${id}/delete`
            type: 'delete',
            success: function(data) {
              // remove selected table tr  
            },
            error: function(data){
            }
        });
```

After send ajax delete row by finding with unique id passed from ajax.

```
Model::find($id)->delete();
return response()->json('Data removed successfully.', 200)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but I didn't get your answer..I just want to add and delete record using same button only with the help of onclick event. Can you plz give me some reference so that I can take help from that